# Can Scorn Earth be used to prevent falling damage?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, falling

Can you use *Scorn Earth* to avoid falling damage since you never actually hit the ground?

> Scorn Earth (Su) At 1st level, an elocater’s feet lift from the
> ground. From now on, she can float a foot above the ground. Instead of
> walking she glides along, unconcerned with the hard earth or difficult
> terrain. While she remains within 1 foot of a flat surface of any
> solid or liquid, she can take normal actions and make normal attacks,
> and can move at her normal speed (she can even “run” at four times her
> normal speed). However, at distances higher than 1 foot above any
> surface, her speed diminishes to 10 feet per round.
>
> While she remains within 1 foot of a surface, she can make melee and
> ranged attacks normally, but if she moves any higher, she incurs the
> penalties on melee and ranged attack rolls as if she were the subject
> of the psionic levitate power.

Comment: What kind of scenario are you imagining that would lead to the elocator falling in the first place?

Comment: @HeyICanChan "walking" (if that's the right term) or being bull-rushed off the edge of a cliff, building or bridge seem to be obvious possibilities.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 And "at distances higher than 1 foot above any surface, her speed diminishes to 10 feet per round." But no falling occurs, so far as I can tell.

Comment: @fectin That's honestly never my intention. I just don't want my answer to dismiss the question's premise then, after answers are posted, have the asker put forth that reasonable scenario that I didn't address. That sucks.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Sorry, I just meant that as encouragement to write what you already had up as an answer!

Comment: @fectin No apology necessary. I'm likely overreacting, having recently had a comment in a similar vein on another question deleted by the mods. Thank you for the encouragement. (And I'd still like a scenario from the asker!)

Answer (score 4):

Scorn earth is written weirdly, because it spends so much time talking about moving around 1 foot away from a surface, that it might suggest that this is all it does.

Buried in the description, however, is

> However, at distances higher than 1 foot above any surface, her speed diminishes to 10 feet per round.
>
> […] if she moves [more than 1 foot from a surface], she incurs the penalties on melee and ranged attack rolls as if she were the subject of the *psionic levitate* power.

Scorn earth prevents falling in the first place, so of course it prevents falling damage. Instead, the elocater just moves 10 feet per round (in any direction they like) until they get a surface under them, and then move normally.

Scorn earth is supernatural, and therefore suppressed by a dead magic zone or similar. An elocater would fall through one of these, and if the floor were within the dead magic, would land and take falling damage. Scorn earth would do nothing, because scorn earth is suppressed and literally does nothing. If an elocater falls through a dead magic zone but comes out into empty air on the other side, scorn earth comes back and they can again control their motion, so their falling stops without taking damage.

Comment: Does that means elocater has infinite non-combat fly (10 ft)

Comment: @NamNguyenHoang It does! At this level, long-duration flight is unusual, but short-duration, tactical flight (e.g. the *fly* spell) becomes fairly common, and is **much** better while it lasts. And at least a few options for long-duration, combat-capable flight are available at this level too, e.g. from dragonborn, raptoran, or warlock.

Comment: At a measly 10 ft/round and stacking -1 attack penalty (max -5) this is not combat-capable, sadly. Unless you switch to forcing saves, instead

Comment: @NamNguyenHoang No, I know. I’m just saying, at this level, there **are** combat-capable options, both short-duration (common; a clear trade-off) and long-duration (relatively uncommon, but available; strictly superior). So long-duration, combat-**in**capable option fits in with the rest of the system fine—if anything, it should be available a couple levels earlier.